# Extract 1024bit modulus from RSA key

Tags: encoding, rsa, public-key, digital-certificate

I know there's a billion answers on how to extract the modulus from an RSA key (I have a `.cer` file) and I want the 1024 bit (it's 1024 bit in my case) value from it. What I don't get is the following:

When I extract it, it's always not 1024 bits, but more. Has that something to do with padding or...? Looks like 136 bytes at the moment, so 64 bit too much. Not sure whether this is a constant or depends on the certificate

edit:
I retried with `openssl x509 -modulus -inform PER -in file.cer` and it resulted in 128 bytes. Guess that's it.

edit2:
So, this still is my problem. I did `openssl x509 -inform DER -in file.cer -text` and got a modulus of 129 bytes. Is my assumption correct that I can skip the first one because it is `0x00` which might just be used to make the whole thing positive again (first byte otherwise would be a `0xaa` which might be negative)?

Comment: There shouldn't be any padding of the modulus. Please provide the method, you're doing this with.

Comment: *Is my assumption correct* - yes, the leading 0x00 is there to make it a positive number.